# What would 'ent'/'eont' be in Modern English?

Tags: historical-change

Based on typical changes, what would the Middle English word 'eont', derived from the Old English 'ent', have become in Modern English, if this word had survived?

Comment: It could possibly survive as _ent_ with the sense(s) of the word "giant" (excluding Tolkien's usage).  However, it didn't survive and [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/giant#:~:text=giant%20(n.)&text=The%20word%20is%20of%20unknown,1330%5D)  has this note for the word _giant_: "It replaced Old English _ent, eoten_, also _gigant_ (from Latin). The Greek word was used in Septuagint to refer to men of great size and strength, hence the expanded use in modern languages". It survived in some German dialects as _Enz_ meaning "giant".

Answer (score 2):

The form that would correspond to Old English *ent* in modern English is ... **ent**, as J. R. R. Tolkien, who was a professor of Anglo-Saxon (in modern terms, Old English), surely knew.

Middle English spelling is fairly unstandardized. Old English had a diphthong spelled *eo* that fell together with the sound of *e* in Middle English. My guess is that this led to spelling variation between "eo" and "e". A specialist on Middle English should be able to tell you more, but I would be surprised to hear of any divergent development that could be attributed to "eo" vs "e" in this context. I would also be surprised if it turns out that this word was consistently and repeatedly spelled "eont" as opposed to "ent" in Middle English: my guess is that the real situation is more like "the few attestations (or single attestation?) that we have of the word in Middle English happen to use the spelling *eont*".

Sorry for all the guessing: I'm not as familiar with resources for Middle English as for modern English. The [Middle English Compendium](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/middle-english-dictionary/dictionary/MED14203/track?counter=1&search_id=26556534) gives only a single quotation, and the following note on the spelling:

> Forms  eont n.
> Etymology   OE ent; spelling eont prob. infl. by OE ēoten giant.

[...]

> Associated quotations
> a1225(OE) Lamb.Hom.Pentec.(Lamb 487)93 : Efter noes flode..**eontas** walden areran ane buruh and anne stepel swa hehne þet his rof astiȝe up to heofena.

For comparison, the Oxford English Dictionary records that the word "end" had a Middle English spelling "eond" which appears to have had no notable impact on this words trajectory:

> Old English–1600s ende, (Middle English aend, aende, Middle English eende, heende, hende, nend(e, Middle English , 1500s eande, Middle English aend, eond, Middle English heynd, 1600s dialect eend), Middle English– end.

Comment: What does Tolkien have to do with it? I don't see the purpose of that reference. (The DV wasn't mine.)

Comment: @MarcInManhattan: I find it hard to imagine that anyone asking about the word "ent" isn't familiar with Tolkien's use of it. And given that his professional work was related to the nature of this question, it does seem relevant to me.

Comment: It is, of course, well known that Tolkien studied Old & Middle English, but I still don't see why that's useful for answering this question. Did he study this word in particular (or related apsects, such as "e" vs. "eo")? What did he say about it?

Comment: @MarcInManhattan: The implicit argument I was thinking of was that if "ent" was a glaringly improbable outcome of this word in modern English, I think it's unlikely Tolkien would have used this form. That isn't a watertight argument, since you could say that perhaps Tolkien was simply using the unadapted Old English form of the word. I think his sensibilities would tend towards using a modernized version, if there was one (compare his use of "wight", not the Old English form "wiht"), so I see his use of "ent" as evidence that there is in fact no distinct form that this word would have taken.

Comment: Oh, I didn't understand that Tolkien had used that word. Is that mentioned in your answer? I might have just missed it, but I've reread your answer and still don't see where it's mentioned.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan: I can't tell whether "I didn't understand that Tolkien had used that word" is serious. Feel free to edit this link into the first sentence if you think it's really needed: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ent I won't be working on this answer further probably!

Comment: Yes, it was serious. I suppose that you thought that a reader would naturally infer from your first sentence that Tolkien had used that word, but I did not infer that. It's possible that I'm an outlier, though.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan: My main assumption was that the OP had encountered it: I find it hard to imagine that someone researching the word "ent" wouldn't quickly run into the fact that it was used by Tolkien to name one of the peoples in his fantasy setting. I don't expect everyone in general to be familiar with that.